# T-estimator is T-Distibuted

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to prove that

$T_n=\frac{\bar{X}_n - \mu}{S/\sqrt{n}}\sim t_{n-1}$.

How do you show this? Is the T-distrbution a ratio between a standard normal and a Chi?

Answer (score -1):

What are the $X_n$'s? what is S? sample variance? Define your variables :|

> Is the T-distrbution a ratio between a standard normal and a Chi?

Well yeah: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Characterization

What you gave seems to look more like this though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Sampling_distribution

Comment: Would've probably been better to ask her to clarify her question using the comments.

Comment: @Olorun Is it correct to say that I did not answer her (/his) question?